# Currently Attempting to Optimize SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently attempting to optimize some SQL queries in a VB format (Ancient, I know) but I'm just attempting to make the queries more efficient.
This is an example of how some of the queries are now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Appointments.WithID, Users.LastName, Users.FirstName
FROM Appointments INNER JOIN AppointmentTypes ONAppointmentTypes.ID = 
Appointments.AppTypeID 
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID = Appointmens.WithID
WHERE Appointments.Hide = 0
ORDER BY Users.LastName, Users.FirstName
```

Above is the initial query that runs, then for all of the results, which generally are the returned Appointments.WithID, A for each loop happens for each item where another query is run, for example below:

```
SELECT Appointments.CustomerID FROM Appointments
WHERE Appointments.Hide = 0
AND Appointments.WithID = (And this is where the "Appointment.WithID's 
from the previous query are entered)
```

So I'm not sure if I explained this properly or not BUT all in all, the second query is run multiple times for EACH Appointment.WithID which is found from the first query. I need a way where I can incorporate the second query within the first so it doesnt run the second query hundreds of times depending on the amount of WithID's returned.

Comment: Add appointments.customerId to the first query.

Comment: just include customerid into first query

Comment: Post result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Appointments`. Create some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you just add the appointments.customerid to your select statement?

Comment: Upvoted to get this guy's rep high enough to post comments.

Comment: The same comment has already been written twice. No need to post it as an answer once more.